# Huffman's encoding and decoding

Tags: huffman-code

I have to build a compressor based on the **Huffman** algorithm.
So far, I managed to create the tree with the frequencies of each character and generate a representation with a smaller number of bits for each character.

Is something like this, for the phrase "good this sugarplum":

> `'o' 000, '' 001, 't' 0100, 'r' 0101, 'p' 0110, 'm' 0111, 'l' 1000, 'i' 1001, 'h' 1010, 'd' 1011, 'a'1100, 'u' 1101, 'g' 1110, 's' 1111`

The problem I'm having now is finding a way to save the tree in the archive, so I can rebuild it and then decompress the file.

Any suggestions?

I did some research but found it difficult to understand, so if you can explain in detail, I would appreciate it.

---

The code I used to read the frequencies from file is:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;

    TipoSentinela *sentinela;

    TipoLista *no = NULL;

    Arv *arvore, *arvore2, *arvore3;

    int *repete = (int *) calloc (256, sizeof(int));

    if(argc == 2)
    {
    in = load_base(argv[1]);
    le_dados_arquivo (repete); //read the frequencies from the file
    sentinela = cria_lista (); //create a marker for the tree node list

    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {   
        if(repete[i] > 0 && i != 0) 
        {
            arvore = arv_cria (Cria_info (i, repete[i])); //create a tree node with the character i and the frequence of it in the file
            no = inicia_lista (arvore, no, sentinela); //create the list of tree nodes
        }
    }

    Ordena (sentinela); //sort the tree nodes list by the frequencies

    for(Seta_primeiro(sentinela); Tamanho_lista(sentinela) != 1; Move_marcador(sentinela))
    {
        Seta_primeiro(sentinela); //put the marker in the first element of the list
        no = Retorna_marcador(sentinela);
        arvore2 = Retorna_arvore (no); //return the tree represented by the list marker
        Move_marcador(sentinela); //put the marker to the next element
        arvore3 = Retorna_arvore (Retorna_marcador (sentinela)); //return the tree represented by the list marker
        arvore = Cria_pai (arvore2, arvore3); //create a tree node that will contain the both arvore2 and arvore3
        Insere_arvoreFinal (sentinela, arvore); //insert the node at the end of the list
        Remove_arvore (sentinela); //remove the node arvore2 from the list
        Remove_arvore (sentinela); //remove the node arvore3 from the lsit
        Ordena (sentinela); //sort the list again

    }

    out = load_out(argv[1]); //open the output file

    Codificacao (arvore); //generate the code from each node of the tree

    rewind(in);

    char c;

    while(!feof(in))
    {
        c = fgetc(in);

        if(c != EOF)
            arvore2 = Procura_info (arvore, c); //search the character c in the tree

        if(arvore2 != NULL)
            imprimebit(Retorna_codigo(arvore2), out); //write the code in the file
    }

    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);
    free(repete);
    arvore = arv_libera (arvore);
    Libera_Lista(sentinela);
    }

    return 0;
}

//bit_counter and cur_byte are global variables
void write_bit (unsigned char bit, FILE *f)
{
    static k = 0;
    if(k != 0)
    {
        if(++bit_counter == 8)
        {
            fwrite(&cur_byte,1,1,f);
            bit_counter = 0;
            cur_byte = 0;
        }
    }

    k = 1;

    cur_byte <<= 1;
    cur_byte |= ('0' != bit);
}

//aux is the code of a character in the tree
void imprimebit(char *aux, FILE *f)
{
    int i, j;

    if(aux == NULL)
        return;

    for(i = 0; i < strlen(aux); i++)
    {
        write_bit(aux[i], f); //write the bits of the code in the file
    }
}
```

With this, I can write the code of all characters in the output file, but I can't see a way to store the tree too.

Comment: Could you post some code to show us what you've tried already?

Comment: I'll edit my post with the code.

Comment: Good, Luiz.  That will help you to get some more activity on your question.  Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. 
I really need to finish this.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to send the tree.  Just send the lengths.  Then establish a consistent algorithm to convert the lengths to codes on both ends.  The consistency is called a "canonical" Huffman code.  You sort the codes by length, and within each length, sort by the symbol.  Then assign codes starting at 0.  So you would end up with (_ means space):

```
_ 000
o 001
a 0100
d 0101
g 0110
h 0111
i 1000
l 1001
m 1010
p 1011
r 1100
s 1101
t 1110
u 1111
```

Comment: "Canonical" is really the typical way to do it. At least start from here, and then you can optimize. An (obvious) link for interesting details : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_Huffman_code

Comment: Since the whole point of using Huffman codes is to reduce the bits sent, the Huffman code itself should be sent using the least number of bits.  The way to do that is to use a canonical code.

Answer (score 0):

I did found a way to store the code of each character.
For example:
I write the tree, starting by the root and going down to the left, then right.
So, if my tree was something like

```
         0
      /    \
    0        1
 /    \     /   \
'a'   'b' 'c'   'd'
```

The header of my file would be someting like this:
001[8 bits from 'a']1[8 bits from b]01[8 bits from c]1[8 bits from d]

With this, I would be able to rebuild my tree.

My problem now is in read bit-by-bit of the header of file to know in wich direction I have to create a new node.